# ComboBox crashing with custom ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, combobox, binding, datatemplate, winui-3

I'm writing a WinUI 3 app and am making a dialog in which the user can select one of multiple object types.

For the ComboBox's ItemTemplate I'm using a TextBlock whose Text is bound to the Name property (to display the Type's Name).

However, if I set the ItemsSource to an array of Type, the application crashes when opening the dropdown menu of the ComboBox with an exception of type Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.UnhandledException. Setting the SelectedIndex property via code has the same effect.

When debugging, the application breaks on the last if statement of the following method in a compiler-generated file named App.g.i.cs.

```
public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            if (_contentLoaded)
                return;

            _contentLoaded = true;

            global::System.Uri resourceLocator = new global::System.Uri("ms-appx:///App.xaml");
            global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator);

#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BINDING_DEBUG_OUTPUT
            DebugSettings.BindingFailed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                global::System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Message);
            };
#endif
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
        }
```

The page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="RayMarchEditor.ChooseObjectTypePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Page>
```

The code-behind:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace RayMarchEditor
{
    public sealed partial class ChooseObjectTypePage : Page
    {
        public ChooseObjectTypePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            comboBox.ItemsSource = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: @Charlieface It's of type System.Ui.Xaml.UnhandledException
[Here](https://imgur.com/a/K5GtJ5E)'s what it looks like in the IDE.

Comment: Please do not post image of code, data or errors, [please paste them in as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), and please put clarifications into the actual question

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry about that. I've edited the post to include more details.

Answer (score 0):

I got to reproduce your error but couldn't get to understand the why. `Type` is an abstract class but that shouldn't be the problem. Maybe this is a **WinUI 3** problem.

Anyway, you need wrap it with a view model class or something and it should work.

**TypeViewModel.cs**

```cs
public class TypeViewModel
{
    public Type Type { get; }

    public TypeViewModel(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

**ChooseObjectTypePage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class ChooseObjectTypePage : Page
{
    public ChooseObjectTypePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        comboBox.ItemsSource = new TypeViewModel[] { new TypeViewModel(typeof(string)) };
    }
}
```

**ChooseObjectTypePage.xaml**

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TypeViewModel">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type.Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```